# Unable to change the value for API key required for REST API via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set an API Key that will be passed as headers like `x-api-key: some-value` which I can do it manually via console and test in my curl request but I am trying it via Terraform.

Below is my code:

```
data "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "api_key" {
  id = ""
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "myusageplan" {
  name = ""

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
    stage  = var.environment
  }
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan_key" "usage_plan_key" {
  key_id        = data.aws_api_gateway_api_key.api_key.id
  key_type      = "API_KEY"
  usage_plan_id = aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.myusageplan.id
}
data "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  path        = "/endpoint"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  name                         = local.rest_api_name
  disable_execute_api_endpoint = true
  body = jsonencode(
    {
      openapi = "3.0.3"
      info = {
        title       = local.rest_api_title
        description = ""
        version     = "0.0.1"
      }
      paths = {

        "/endpoint" = {
          post = {
            x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
              httpMethod           = "POST"
              payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
              type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
              uri                  = aws_lambda_function.api_lambda.invoke_arn
              passthroughBehavior  = "when_no_match"
              contentHandling      = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
              type                 = "aws_proxy"
              request_parameters = {
                "method.request.header.X-API-KEY" = "method.request.querystring.apikey"
              }
              responses = {
                default = {
                  statusCode = "500"
                }
              }
            }
            requestBody = {
              description = "A provisioning request descriptor wrapped as a string into a simple object"
              schema = {
                "$ref" = "#/definitions/CustomNotificationRequest"
              }
              required = true
            }
            responses = {
              "202" = {
                description = "It asynchronously returns the request result"
                schema = {
                  "$ref" = "#/definitions/Response"
                }
              }
              "200" = {
                description = "If successful returns a provisioning deployment task token that can be used for polling the request status"
                schema = {
                  "$ref" = "#/definitions/TraceableResponse"
                }
              }
              "400" = {
                description = "Invalid input"
                schema = {
                  "$ref" = "#/definitions/ValidationError"
                }
              }
              "500" = {
                description = "System problem"
                schema = {
                  "$ref" = "#/definitions/SystemError"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }
      definitions = {

        CustomNotificationRequest = {
          type = "object"
          properties = {
            respondToUrl = {
              type        = "string"
              description = "URL to be contacted to notify that the hook is completed. This represents the fact that the third-party interaction has been performed on your end"
            }
            fields = {
              type        = "object"
              description = "A free-form object containing all the action's input data coming from witboost"
            }

          }
        }
        AsyncRespone = {
          type = "object"
          properties = {
            hookInfo = {
              type = "string"
            }
          }
        }
        TraceableRespone = {
          type = "object"
          properties = {
            externalUrl = {
              type = "string"
            }
          }
        }
        ValidationError = {
          type = "object"
          properties = {
            errors = {
              type = "array"
              items = {
                type = "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }

        SystemError = {
          type = "object"
          properties = {
            error = {
              type = "string"
            }
          }
        }



    } }
  )


  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "rest_api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.body)
  }
  variables = {
    deployed_at = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "rest_api_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.rest_api_deployment.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  stage_name    = var.environment
}
```

This code refers to the creation of an API gateway with an endpoint mapping and some documentation explanation. Also it has usage plan where it links the API key with the stage which I confirmed from the console that it is properly linked. The only thing that it is not doing is changing the value in the below screenshot from `False` to `True`.

[image]

I referred to the official documentation and added request parameters, and variables in the deployment but nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong here? Any hints are also appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: My problem is similar to this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5528. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved my problem after a lot of trial and errors. You need to create the below things:

1. **aws_api_gateway_resource**
2. **aws_api_gateway_method**
3. **aws_rest_api**
4. **aws_api_gateway_integration**
5. **aws_api_gateway_deployment**
6. **aws_lambda_function**
7. **aws_api_gateway_usage_plan**
8. **aws_api_gateway_usage_plan_key**
9. **aws_api_gateway_api_key**

**Note**: If your endpoint path is like `"/abc/some-thing/"` then you need two resources one would be for `abc` and other would be for `some-thing`.

Also, ensure that the mapping of `IDs` are correct and your `api_gateway_deployment` should depend on the `aws_api_gateway_integration` part and your integration part should depend on the `aws_api_gateway_method` resource.

Referring to documentation is the best way. I really appreciate terraform's documentation. It was the only savior.